# Upsert fails unless the primary key is reassigned on conflict

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm using the following library https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert to generate upsert commands for Postgres, and the command doesn't seem to update the row unless the primary key column is also modified in the `ON CONFLICT` section.

Command that doesn't update the row:

```
INSERT INTO "Table" AS "T" 
( "id", "active", "status", "price", "modified_date") 
  VALUES 
  (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4), 
  (@p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9)  
  ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE 
  SET 
  "modified_date" = EXCLUDED."modified_date",  
  "active" = EXCLUDED."active",
```

Command that works (here I'm just assigning the `id` primary key to a random value)

```
INSERT INTO "Table" AS "T" 
( "id", "active", "status", "price", "modified_date") 
  VALUES 
  (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4), 
  (@p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9)  
  ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE 
  SET 
  "id" = @p10
  "modified_date" = EXCLUDED."modified_date",  
  "active" = EXCLUDED."active",
```

Any help would be appreciated.

As mentioned above I've reassigned the primary key to an arbitrary value and that updates the row as expected, however, I don't want to re-assign the primary key for obvious reasons.

I've even tried using a unique index from the table, and that doesn't upsert the row as expected.

Table Definition (Using EFCore as the ORM):

```
public class Table
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public bool Active {get; set;}

    public string Status {get; set;}

    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the DDL for your table, including the indexes and constraints?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this, I have no clue how EFCore works and what kind of DDL it generates.

Comment: I've updated the description to include the C# model that's powering the table. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You say "it fails", but you don't show an error message.

Comment: It fails in the sense that the first update did not change the record as expected. While the second one did.

Comment: Yes that's right. I expected the first query to update